# Error while creating Sales Order with "API_SALES_ORDER_SRV"

Tags: s4sdk

we want to create a Sales Order with Cloud SDK (Version 1.9.2) using Virtual Data Model (A_SalesOrder) in our Java Application. 
We are calling S4 OnPremise System (1709).

```
SalesOrder so = SalesOrder.builder()
                    .salesOrderType("ZKE")
                    .salesOrganization("DE01")
                    .distributionChannel("01")
                    .organizationDivision("00")
                    .build();

try {
        SalesOrder salesOrder = new 
       SalesOrderCreateFluentHelper(so).execute(endpoint);

} ....
```

We are getting the following error (while executing via PostMan):

```
"errordetails": [
        {
          "code": "CX_SADL_ENTITY_SRVICE_NOT_SUPP",
          "message": "The requested service  is not supported by entity ~A_SALESORDER",
          "propertyref": "",
          "severity": "error",
          "target": ""
        },
        {
          "code": "/IWBEP/CX_MGW_MED_EXCEPTION",
          "message": "An exception was raised",
          "propertyref": "",
          "severity": "error",
          "target": ""
        }
      ]
```

Can somebody give us a advise to create a Sales Order via the API? 
How we can create Sales Order Items for this Sales Order in one Step?

Thanks!

Additional information OData Request Data 
(Response Data not provided in ERROR_LOG):

Request-Header / Request-Body:
 [image: Request-Header]
[image: Request-Body]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently we received this error message because we did not include any items in the request. If you give it in your body it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Can you pls share the OData request and response body and payload?
Open transaction /IWFND/ERROR_LOG, choose the error message and in the lower part of the screen, choose Request Data resp. Response Data and provide us both body and header. Make sure to omit any confidential data.

Comment: Pls look at our question above for the OData Request Data. Response Date are not provided from the Error_log.